# using HttpWebRequest two or more times via c#

Tags: c#, facebook, api, httpwebrequest

I have one problem. I have two methods which use  HttpWebRequest.  One of them post a message to my facebook wall.  Another take count number of likes.
Thare is code:

```
 if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string url =
                    string.Format(
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                        app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }
                //get wall data
                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);


                //post message to my wall or image
                dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();


                messagePost.message = "I need to get an id of this post";

                try
                {
                    var postId = client.Post("me/feed", messagePost);
                    id_mypost = postId["id"];
                }
                catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
                {
                    //handle oauth exception
                }
                catch (FacebookApiException ex)
                {
                    //handle facebook exception
                }
            }
```

This method post message to my wall.  Thare is the second method:

```
if (Response.BufferOutput == true)
            {
                if (Request["code"] == null)
                {

                    Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                        app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
                }
                else
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                    string url =
                        string.Format(
                            "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                            app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                        string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                        {
                            //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                            tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                                token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                        }
                    }

                    string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
                    var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
                    try
                    {
                    string str = client.Get("/me/feed").ToString();
                    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(str);
                    JToken jUser = obj["data"];
                    int numb = jUser.Count();
                    int id_post = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                    {
                        if (obj["data"][i]["id"].ToString() == id_mypost)
                        {
                            id_post = i;
                        }
                    }
                    string strr = obj["data"][id_post]["likes"].ToString();

                    string pattern = @"id";
                    int count_like = 0;
                    Regex newReg = new Regex(pattern);
                    MatchCollection matches = newReg.Matches(strr);
                    foreach (Match mat in matches)
                    {
                        count_like++;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
```

So thare is the problem. I use two times  HttpWebRequest. So , when I bild my app i got next error:  Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

This is the error of asynchronous operation. For example if you are using any thread operation and in that thread you try Response.redirect it will give this error.

The response is already sent to client before the statement executes.

Can you please tell me where exactly the error is occurring ?

Comment: In that line in the second method  Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                        app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));